# SSHing into a machine that has several realms in its /etc/krb5.conf

Tags: ssh, kerberos

Due to some requirements, a set of machines I use needs to have 2 KDCs defined in `/etc/krb5.conf`. On top of that, the realm that doesn't contain user principles (just host and service principals) must be specified as the default realm under `libdefaults`.

The user principals are stored in the other realm and ssh is supposed to work through that realm. The sshd config also uses PAM. In PAM, I've overriden the default realm with `realm=MY_SECOND_REALM` for the account interface and my ssh logins now work.

The only problem is that my logins now require a password -- each time despite my valid tickets for the `MY_SECOND_REALM`.

I'm also using sssd. Quite a setup!

Did I miss something simple?

Comment: Let's see your /etc/krb5.conf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few hours of playing with my pam auth modules, I figured out a way to circumvent the problem by using the `realm=MY_SECOND_REALM` as an argument to the pam_krb line in the `account` section.

From the `pam_krb5` man page:

> realm=realm
>   overrides the default realm set in /etc/krb5.conf, 
>   which > pam_krb5.so will attempt to authenticate users to.

Comment: Please self-mark your answer as accepted. This signposts it to others who may also be searching about this problem.